How to make the following script much faster when turned into an .exe (CoolProp)
I am trying to make my excel file (which uses CoolProp functions) independent of the actual excel CoolProp Add-In so that I can distribute it to others without them needing thr Add-In.
I got the idea of turning the following script into an .exe, and calling it from Excel whenever a cell is using the formula.
When turned into an .exe however, it takes 0.8 seconds per calculation. If you multiply this by more than 100 cells in my excel file, you can imagine it takes too much time for each cell to call the .exe and retrieve the results.
import sys
from CoolProp.CoolProp import HAPropsSI

def calculate_coolprop(inp1,inp2,inp3,inp4,inp5):
    result = HAPropsSI(inp1, inp2, inp3, inp4, inp5, "P", 101325)
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp1 = str(sys.argv[1])
    inp2 = str(sys.argv[2])
    inp3 = float(sys.argv[3])
    inp4 = str(sys.argv[4])
    inp5 = float(sys.argv[5])
    
    output = calculate_coolprop(inp1,inp2,inp3,inp4,inp5)
    
    print(output)

When using cProfile, I see the functions taking the most time are python .io built-in functions such as io.open_code(). Therefore I was thinking maybe python was not the way to go.
Any ideas ? I greatly appreciate the help.

Calling an external executable for each cell calculation is indeed inefficient due to the overhead of launching a new process each time.  Instead of making an exe, you could create a COM server that stays running and handles multiple requests. This would eliminate the process creation overhead.
You could also create a service that runs continuously and communicates with Excel via a faster IPC mechanism.
